# How to get user_location through Facebook Login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I need to get the **user_location** through the Facebook login API.

I was able to successfully implement facebook login with JavaScript and I can currently get: name, birthday, gender, hometown (=where the person was born) and id. I am unable to get the user_location listed in facebook profiles (= where the person lives). Also, I have already granted access to my location when logging into the app with Facebook.

Here's my code:

```
<!-- FB log-in -->
<script>
  
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v14.0'
    });
      
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
    /*
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        loginStatusChangeCallback(response);
    });
    */
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function loginStatusChangeCallback(response){
    
    if(response.status=='connected'){
        //alert('Logged into FB and into app.');
        
        FB.api('/me', { locale: 'it_IT', fields: 'name, email, birthday, hometown, education, gender, website, work' },
          function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        );
        
    }else if(response.status=='not_authorized'){
        //alert('Logged into FB but NOT into app.');
        //FB.login();
    }else if(response.status=='unknown'){
        //alert('Not logged into FB.');
        //FB.login();
    }
    
    console.log(response);
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    loginStatusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

</script>
```

Output example:

```
{
birthday: "07/21/1994"
email: "contact@myemail.com"
gender: "male"
hometown: {id: '115351801811432', name: 'Torino'}
id: "1234567891324567"
name: "Luca Smith"
}
```

I have the permissions for user_location:

[image]

However, it seems like Facebook does not care. How do I get **user_location**?

Comment: Did the user grant user_location permission to the app?

Comment: Yes! He did, as well as for other things like user_link...however, Facebook doesn't notice, nor it gives me any error...

Comment: Debug the access token. Does it say it has user_location permission? If so file a bug with Facebook.

Comment: I debugged the access token. It does have user_location mentioned. However, I can't get its value with JavaScript...

Comment: Can you get it using the Graph API debugger using the access token?

Comment: Got it thanks! I didn't know about that tool :) In the end I had to change my JavaScript to this: "FB.api('/me', { locale: 'it_IT', fields: 'name, email, birthday, hometown, education, gender, website, work, link, location' },"